# convert JavaScript byte array to Python datatype

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have an application/service with which I'm attempting to interface. The service sends JavaScript byte arrays raw over to the native JavaScript client. From what I can tell, the client basically shoves the series of binary bytes into a variable. For clarity, the following is how the native JavaScript client handles this data:

```
t.prototype.responseToMsg = function(t) {
  var i, r, u;
  return n.Msg.isMsg(t) ? t : (i = "",
  true ? true ? (r = new Uint8Array(t),
  i = this.decode(r)) : (u = this.parseStr(t),
  i = this.decode(u)) : i = t,
  angular.fromJson(i))
}
```

JavaScript is syntactically familiar but otherwise not something I use. This code is somewhat obfuscated / minified.

So my client is written in Python, and I have limited modules available in my environment. I can't use something like a Python module to evaluate it natively in JavaScript, nor do I want to make external calls to something like `node.js` - I think these probably introduce additional problems with implementation.

What would be great would be to someway convert the byte array to a dictionary or some other format in Python. If I can get there, I can handle the JSON deserialization later.

Is there a way to parse or convert this raw data to a usable Python datatype?